# C: Getting string containing spaces between two strings

Tags: c, linux, string

I'm able to get a string between two strings using the following function :

```
 char* parsedData = NULL;

 const char* const parseData(char* theString, char* start, char* end){
      if (!theString) return 0;                               
      size_t startSize = strlen(start);                
      char* startP = strstr (theString,start);        
      if(!startP)
           return 0;                           
      startP+=startSize;                              
      char* endP = strstr ((startP),end);            
      if(!endP)
           return 0;                             
      //free(parsedData);                              
      parsedData = NULL;
      parsedData = (char*) malloc((size_t)(sizeof(char)*(endP-startP)+1));       
      if (parsedData == NULL) {
           return 0;
      }     
      int dataPos=0;
      while ( startP != endP ){                       
           parsedData[dataPos++]= *startP++;
      }
      parsedData[dataPos]= '\0';                      
      return parsedData;                                     
 }
```

There are two problems I'm having here.

1. This works when my string doesn't have spaces in it, but doesn't wok otherwise.
   When I print the string, I only get (null).
2. When I uncomment the `free()` line, I get `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer:` error and the program crashes.

How can I solve this ?

/******************************************EDIT 1******************************************/

Following Steen's answer, I realised problem 1 was due to lack of error checking elsewhere. I confirm the function works both with and without spaces.

/******************************************EDIT 2******************************************/

I have changed the code following Hyde's suggestions:

```
const char* const parseData(char* theString, char* start, char* end){
    char* tmpstr;
    if (!theString) return 0;        
    size_t startSize = strlen(start); 
    char* startP = strstr (theString,start);
    if(!startP) return 0; 
    startP+=startSize; 
    char* endP = strstr ((startP),end); 
    if(!endP) return 0; 
    if (parsedData != NULL){ free(parsedData);} 
    parsedData = NULL;
    parsedData = (char*) malloc((size_t)(sizeof(char)*(endP-startP)+1)); 
    if (parsedData == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }  

    int dataPos=0;
    while ( startP != endP ){ 
        parsedData[dataPos++]= *startP++;
    }
    parsedData[dataPos]= '\0'; 
    tmpstr = parsedData;
    return tmpstr; 
}
```

I'm calling the function this way:

```
const char* const usr1 = parseData(buffer, ":", ",");
const char* const usr2 = parseData(buffer, ",", ".");
const char* const usr3 = parseData(buffer, "(", ")");

printf("%s, %s, %s\n", usr1, usr2, usr3);
```

But the output is always:

`<usr3>, <usr3>, <usr3>`

Comment: Works for me just fine http://ideone.com/wag014

Comment: `free(parsedData);` is at un proper place in code. This is suitable where you catch this returned buffer.

Comment: You shouldn't touch the global variable in that function. Just return value of a local pointer variable (allocated memory is in the heap, so will outlive the function scope). Actually you shouldn't probably have the global variable at all, but the point is, move the responsibility of taking care of the pointer to caller.

Comment: Remove the cast on the result of `malloc()`, enable all warnings (`-Wall - Wextra -pedantic` for gcc) and recompile. Fix the code until no more warnings are issued by the compiler.

Comment: free(parsedData) was placed there to free the pointer on subsequent function calls, before allocating memory again.
I'm trying to get rid of all warnings now.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to find the address of a sub string, given a start address and a end address. Returning the address of the found substring or if search fails, return null.  If this is a correct interpretation, then see me answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function works for me both with and without spaces in parameter.

You will have to guard your `free(parsedData)` with a `if (parsedData != NULL)` otherwise you will be freeing a NULL-pointer at first pass

I would try something along this line:

```
const char* const parseData(char* theString, char* start, char* end){
  #define PARSE_ELEMENT_MAX_SIZE 256
  static char parsedData[ PARSE_ELEMENT_MAX_SIZE ];

  if ( theString == NULL || start == NULL || end == NULL ) {
    return 0;        
  }
  size_t startSize = strlen(start); 
  char* startP = strstr (theString,start);
  if( startP == NULL ) {
    return 0; 
  }
  startP+= startSize; 
  char* endP = strstr (startP, end); 
  if( endP == NULL || endP - startP >= PARSE_ELEMENT_MAX_SIZE ) {
    return 0; 
  }
  memcpy( parsedData, startP, endP - startP );
  parsedData[ endP - startP ]= 0;
  return parsedData; 
}
```

If you want to preserve data between concequtive calls, you will have to let the caller own the buffer, and not allocate it in the parseData function:

```
BOOL parseData(char* theString, char* start, char* end,
    char *parsedData, size_t MaxSizeOfParsedData ){

  if ( theString == NULL || start == NULL || end == NULL || parsedData == NULL ) {
    return FALSE;        
  }
  char* startP = strstr (theString,start);
  if( startP == NULL ) {
    return FALSE; 
  }
  startP+= strlen(start); 
  char* endP = strstr (startP, end); 
  if( endP == NULL || endP - startP >= MaxSizeOfParsedData ) {
    return FALSE; 
  }
  memcpy( parsedData, startP, endP - startP );
  parsedData[ endP - startP ]= 0;
  return TRUE; 
}
```

Comment: The C-Standard explicitly allows `NULL` to be passed to `free()`.

Comment: You're right about 1. Thanks for taking out the time to test it.
I tried your suggestion, but with this change, the function seems to return the same value on subsequent calls. I wonder if this is a problem somewhere else, but I havent changed anything else.

Comment: Hard to say. You could drop the malloc, and return data from an array of fixed size (char parsedData[MAX_SIZE]). If you are experiencing problems in the heap, this would remove the problem from this function:)

Comment: @Steen Just what do you mean by "return data from an array of fixed size"? Did you forget to mention it needs to be `static`, or did you mean something else?

Comment: static is optional, but is the best way to declare it to avoid linking problems. I meant a construct like this: `static char parsedData[ MAX_SIZE ];`

 `const char* const parseData(char* theString, char* start, char* end){`

Comment: Steen and hyde: I have edited the question with the changes I made to the code following your advices. Could you please have a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

```
 const char* const findSubStr(char* pSearchStr, char* pStrStart, char* pStrEnd)
 {
    // validate parameters
    if (!pSearchStr) return 0;
    if (!pStrStart) return 0;
    if (!pStrEnd) return 0;
    if (pStrEnd <= pStrStart) return 0;

    int   WorkStrLen = pStrEnd - pStrStart +2; // allows for terminator byte

    // get work area so can modify original string with terminator byte
    char* pWorkStr = malloc(WorkStrLen); 
    if( NULL == pWorkStr ) return 0; // check for malloc failure

    // clear work area and copy target string 
    memset( pWorkStr, 0x00, WorkStrLen );    
    memcpy( pWorkStr, pStrStart, (WorkStrLen -1) ); // avoid overlaying term byte

    // find the search string
    char* pFoundStr = strstr( pWorkStr, pSearchStr );
    // verify string found
    if ( NULL == pFoundStr ) return 0; // search string wasn't found

    int offset = pFoundStr - pWorkStr;
    free( pWorkStr );
    return( &pStrStart[offset] );  // return ptr to found substring                        
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to use this function. It returns null always. 
Always returns at if(pStrEnd <= pStrStart).
I'm using it as "const char* const usr = findSubStr(buffer, ":", ",");". The buffer is nul terminated. 
Could you please check and update?

Comment: the check `if (pStrEnd <= pStrStart) return 0;` is wrong. It compares the physical position in memory of the pointers of the start end end string